# Типы передаваемых сообщений в микросервисах

Tags: rabbitmq, микросервисы

В реальных приложениях десятки и сотни микросервисов, которые передают друг другу сообщения разных форматов (текст, число, какие-то объекты, файлы и т.д.).. Причем один микросервис например может передавать много раз текст или число или файл.

Объясните пожалуйста несколько вещей:

1. На каждый тип передаваемого сообщения создается поставщик, который может принять конкретный тип и потребитель, который может принять сообщение этого типа или как поступают?
2. Можно ли один поставщик или потребитель использовать несколько раз, для отправки или принятия сообщения многократно?

Comment: Если сообщение отправляется куда то, то его кто то должен принять. Нет смысла в сообщениях отправленых в никуда. Или я не понял вопрос

Comment: Понято что если отправляется сообщение его кто-то должен принять. Вопрос был в том если например передается число или строка или объект какой-то на каждый такой случай создается поставщик и получатель, которые могут передать и принять сообщение определенного типа или можно написать какой-то универсальный поставщик и получатель используя дженерики например?

Если например микросервис должен пересылать десятки различных объектов типа Car, Phone и т.д. для каждого отдельно писать?

Comment: Оно может быть и так, и так. Не припомню каких то строгих правил, как передавать сообщения.